Flow-How to use a string variable in Condition Expression?
I have a dynamic logic string: 1 and (2 or 3)
and conditions:

Region equals Japan
Owner equals Jim
Owner equals Mary

Because the conditions and the logic string are dynamic, I'm using Power Automate to parse these conditions into a condition expression:
and(equals(Region,"Japan"),or(equals(Owner,Jim"),equals(Owner,"Mary")))

Then evaluate whether this condition expression is true or false, but when I reference this variable in a condition action, it always results to False, because it doesn't recognize the string as an expression.
I've also tried initializing a Boolean variable using the string, but same it returns the error:

The variable 'Reference Raw Logic Variable' of type 'Boolean' cannot be initialized or updated with value of type 'String'.

Other methods I've tried: (x as the string variable)
concat(@,x)
bool(x)

Is there a way I can use this string condition expression and evaluate if it is true/false?
Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

What is "Region" and "Owner" exactly? Are those variables or column values coming from any other action?

If you are trying to make "Region" and "Owner" as variables in the Power automate flow and use those in condition expressions, use flow like below:

Note: Both sides of "condition" are added as expression from "Dynamic content >> Expression" option:

Left hand side expression:
and(equals(variables('Region'),'Japan'),or(equals(variables('Owner'),'Jim'),equals(variables('Owner'),'Mary')))

Right hand side expression:
true

Output:

